# MockMvc no such bean exception

Tags: spring-boot

I get a no such bean exception when I try to use mock mvc. It looks like the auto configure mvc method is not working. No sure why this is happening.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 28 more
```

Below is the code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = AssessmentanalyticsApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AssessmentanalyticsApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        AssessmentAttemptData data = new AssessmentAttemptData();
        data.setAssessmentAttemptCount("1");
        data.setAssessmentCompletionCount("2");
        data.setAssessmentId("1");
        data.setHighScore(new BigDecimal(1));
        data.setLowScore(new BigDecimal(1));
         MvcResult result = (MvcResult) mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/assessmentanalytics/recordAttempt")
             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this JUnit 4 or 5?

Comment: This is junit 4